# DPM Error 31314 Protecting Hyper-V After Installing Updates

Tags: hyper-v, failover, scdpm

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Failover Cluster to provide high availability for several Hyper-V virtual machines. I've used Data Protection Manager in the past to protect Hyper-V in a failover cluster, and I'm trying to get it set up again.

I've installed the DPM agent on each of the nodes in the cluster and configured storage/etc in DPM. However, when I attempt to add any of the virtual machines to a protection group, I get the following error message:

> One or more prerequisites for protecting this data source is missing.
>   Ensure that the following prerequisite software is installed on all the nodes in the cluster:
>
> Windows Server 2008 with
>   Knowledge Base article 948465 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948465)
>           AND
>   Knowledge Base article 971394 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971394)
>           - OR -
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 with 
>   Knowledge Base article 975921(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975921) 
>           AND 
>   Knowledge Base article 975354(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975354)
>
> If you have already installed the required prerequisite, refresh the agent status in the management tab and try again.
>
> ID: 31314

I went on Microsoft's website and requested those hotfixes (KB 975921 and 975354) and installed them on each node of the cluster, then restarted each of the nodes in the cluster. Afterward, I refreshed the agent information for each of the nodes. However, I still received the error message.

I've restarted both DPM and each of the nodes a few times, and still receive the error message.

After some research online, I found a blog (listed below) which mentions that the hotfix for KB 975354  is supposed to contain *two* updates that apparently have to be installed in a particular order; however, when I downloaded the hotfix, it only contained one file.

A few other notes:

- This is not a new installation of DPM. In fact, it is already successfully protecting some VM's in this cluster. However, recently I had to re-build all of the nodes in this cluster (one at a time) because of some anti-virus software that got installed on them and corrupted the OS.
- I'm running DPM 2010, and all of the nodes are running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- I haven't tried adding any non-highly available VM's to a protection group.

At this point, I'm still receiving the same error and am unable to add my Hyper-V VM's to a protection group. Does anybody know how to get this to work?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mattmcspirit/archive/2010/03/26/dpm-2010-rc-and-hyper-v-r2-vm-s-on-csv-s-order-of-patches.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a support case with Microsoft about this problem. They had me go to the control panel on each node and select "Uninstall a program," and then "View installed updates." Despite the fact that opening the hotfix would give a message that it was already installed, the control panel didn't have it listed (in fact, it said that no updates had been installed at all). When I removed that node from the cluster, DPM worked fine. The support rep was going to have me use the System Update Readiness Tool to diagnose the problem, but I decided to simply rebuild that node (Windows Deployment Services makes rebuilding pretty easy). All is working fine now.